# Trying to Scrape Reference Links From Wikipedia with BeautifulSoup But I keep Getting None as Output

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the reference links from wiki page but i keep getting None as Output.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests,lxml

webs=requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment')
soup=BeautifulSoup(webs.content,'lxml')
links=soup.find('div', {'class':'reflist'})
print(links.get('href'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested this code with the given wikipedia page and it returns a list containing each link as a string.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests,lxml

webs=requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment')
soup=BeautifulSoup(webs.content,'html.parser')
links=soup.find_all('a', class_ = 'external text', rel = 'nofollow')
map = map(str , links)
result = []
for link in map:
    result.append(link[link.find('href=\"')+6:link.find('rel=')-2])
print(result)
```